# Order by a string by numbers with QueryExpression

Tags: dynamics-crm, sql-order-by, crm, query-expressions

I'm having a problem ordering numbers that are saved as string in CRM,

Its working fine until 10, then it says that 9 > 10 I know a simple solution where I can append zeros to the strings into a fixed length.
Wondering if there is a way to order by a string by int in some way.

My code:

```
       QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression(entity);
       query.ColumnSet.AddColumn(ID);
       query.AddOrder(ID, OrderType.Descending); //there is a problem because the type is string.
       EntityCollection entityCollection = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any easy way of achieving this. I faced the same issue for the post code and ended up storing both values i.e. string and int. And while querying i used the int field to sort it.

Comment: Thanks, guess that is another way of solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution to this problem would be to sort the results of the query using LINQ's `OrderBy()` method instead of using `QueryExpression`'s built in ordering.

```
EntityCollection results = _client.RetrieveMultiple(query);

var sortedResults = results.Entities.OrderBy((e) => 
                    int.Parse(e.GetAttributeValue<string>("nameofattribute"))
                    );
```

This will yield the results your looking for. It isn't an ideal solution but at least you don't have to store everything twice.

Comment: We tested at our work LINQ vs QueryExpression, It seemed to be that QueryExpression execution time is slightly faster than LINQ.
That why I wanted to do it with QueryExpression. Also this answer seems bad to me because first you retrieve all of the information and then you query it again.

Comment: Yes, this solution has a slower run-time than perhaps a better solution would. In theory, the LINQ expression here should run relatively quickly because everything is being done in memory instead of over a network, but you still have a basic overhead of sorting a list (which could be quite high depending on how much data you are working with). I personally think that @RaviKashyap solution is better than mine, but the disadvantage there is you end up storing everything twice for this field, and need a system to keep these values synchronized.